# What's the fallacy here?

Tags: calculus

Can anybody find the fallacy in the below argument? I have used the symmetric definition of the double derivative and that gives me a crazy consequence...

$$f''(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-2f(x_0)+f(x_0-(x-x_0))}{(x-x_0)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)+f(x_0-(x-x_0))-f(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)+f(2x_0-x)-f(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^2}$$
Now let $g(x)=f(2x_0-x)$, then $g'(x_0)=-f'(x_0)$
$$f''(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)+g(x)-g(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)+(x-x_0)g'(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)-(x-x_0)f'(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{\sum_0^\infty\frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i-f(x_0)+(x-x_0)g'(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{\sum_2^\infty\frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i}{(x-x_0)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} f''(x)$$

Comment: $g'$ is not correct.

Comment: @Cbjork The computation of $g'(x_0)$ is fine.  The error is in not expanding $g(x)$ to at least second order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the step where you replace $g(x)-g(x_0)$ by its local linear approximation, $(x-x_0)g'(x_0)$.  You need to keep terms up to second order:
$$
g(x)-g(x_0)\approx(x-x_0)g'(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)^2g''(x_0).
$$
In other words, you cannot assume that this second order term vanishes in the limit.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to TheSimpliFire's note, I suspect you have confused yourself by using $x_0$ notation. Your definition of $f''$ treats the real variable as $x_0$, but later you subtly to switch to $x$.

After your definition of $f''$, you should have defined $g$ as $g(x_0) = f(2x_0 - x)$, *not* $g(x)$, and you won't get the contradiction.

In effect, you have defined a totally different curve $g$, and stated a point of intersection, and then falsely assumed that the local derivatives of the two curves $f$ and $g$ have to align.

Comment: It appears that $g(x)$ is introduced in order to discuss the local approximation of $f(2x_0-x)-f(x_0)$ when $x$ is close to $x_0$.  I see no problem with that.  The source of the error is in approximating $g(x)$ only to first order in $x-x_0$ rather than to second order.  See my answer.

Comment: That's what I meant by "falsely assumed that the local derivatives of the two curves $f$ and $g$ have to align." In other words, there is no *a priori* reason to think that $f(2x_0 - x) - f(x_0)$ even *has* a local approximation, e.g. it might be non-differentiable or not twice-differentiable.

Comment: If $f$ is twice differentiable then so is the function of $x$ given by $f(2x_0-x)-f(x_0)$.

Comment: Yes of course, but only as functions of the variable $x_0$, whereas the OP uses $g(x)$, like I said this is the main error.

Comment: If $f''(x_0)$ exists than $f$ is twice differentiable at $x_0$ and therefore once differentiable at $x_0$.  The function of $x$ defined by $\ell(x)=2x_0-x$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and takes the value $x_0$ when $x=x_0$.  Therefore, by the chain rule, the function of $x$ defined by $g(x)=f(\ell(x))$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $g'(x_0)=f'(\ell(x_0))\ell'(x_0)=-f'(x_0)$.  So the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ have the same magnitude and opposite sign at $x_0$.  One can similarly show that the second derivatives of $f$ and $g$ have the same magnitude and the **same** sign at $x_0$.